# Запуск анимации на определенном экземпляре префаба

Tags: unity3d

Не могу решить одну задачу. У меня есть один префаб, где на нем записана его анимация. Во время игры моя задача расставить несколько таких префабов т.е делаются клоны префаба. Вопрос в том, мне нужно чтобы анимация воспроизводилась  у определенного префаба который я укажу курсором. И еще, расставить эти экземпляры могу в разном порядке при каждом новом запуске игры
Какими путями можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для выбора объектов тебе нужно пускать луч из камеры в точку пространства, расчитанную из экранных координат. У твоих объектов должен быть коллайдер, чтобы регистрировать лучи и маска, которую твой луч "видит"

```
         if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
         {
             RaycastHit hitInfo = new RaycastHit();
             if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hitInfo))
             {
                 animator.SetTrigger("YourAnimationStateName");
             }
         }
```

Ну, понятное дело, на твоём префабе должен быть компонент Animator, в который ты добавишь ссылку на AnimatorController с твоими анимациями.

Чтобы расставить рандомно, самое простое это взять какую-то базовую точку в пространстве и к ней добавить какой-то рандомный вектор Vector3(Random.Range(-range, range),Random.Range(-range, range),Random.Range(-range, range)), где range это границы в метрах от той базовой точки.

Answer (score -1):

А как можно объеденить все анимации в префабе чтобы можно было вызвать их разом?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть дочерние объекты, в каждом их низ есть анимация.

Comment: А вы сделайте скрипт в котором будет массив со ссылками на все аниматоры и запускайте через него, а если все анимации работают только вместе то еще проще, сделайте таймлинию и на ней все анимации разместите)